# Understanding C vs its Assembly counterpart

Tags: c, assembly, x86

Say we are given a function:

```
    int exchange(int*xp, int y)
    {
    x = *xp; 
    *xp = y; 
    return x;

    }
```

So, the book I am reading explains that xp is stored at offsets 8 and 12 relative to the address register %ebp. What I am not understanding is why they are stored as any kind of unit 8 and 12, further more: What is an offset in this context? Finally, how do 8 and 12 fit when the register accepts movement in units of 1 2 and 4 bytes respectively?

The assembly code :

```
xp at %ebp+8, y at%ebp+12 
1 movl 8(%ebp), %edx (Get xp By copying to %eax below, x becomes the return value)

2 movl (%edx), %eax (Get x at xp) 

3 movl 12(%ebp), %ecx (Get y) 

4 movl %ecx, (%edx) (Store y at xp)
```

What I think the answer is: 
So, when examining registries, it was common to see something like registry %rdi holding a value of 0x1004 which is an address and 0x1004 is in the address which holds a value 0xAA.

Of course, this is a hypothetical example that doesn't line up with the registries listed in the book. Each registry is 16-32 bit and the top four can be used to store integers freely. Does offsetting it by 8 make it akin to 0x1000 + 8? Again, I'm not entirely sure what the offset in this scenario is for when we are storing new units into empty space.

Comment: *Does offsetting it by 8 make it akin to 0x1000 + 8?* Yes, this is called [indexed addressing](http://chortle.ccsu.edu/assemblytutorial/Chapter-24/ass24_11.html).

Comment: Right! The book mentioned this when describing how pop and push worked in relation to the stack! It's beginning to make sense, but how do I know what addresses are IN my registry? Does each point of the registry each have addresses 0x1000 , 0x1004, 0x1008? Or do they all have the share addresses? (I feel like this book is simultaneously trying to get me to think and make fun of me with a knowing smile) Also, why offset it by 8 or 12 rather than 4 or 2?

Comment: There is no registry, only registers. That's something else. A register just holds a value (32 bit in your case). The meaning of this value is not something the processor is concerned about. Example: eax may contain 0x000003E8, and that may indicate your account balance of $1000 (0x3E8=1000) or it may be a memory address (a pointer), let's say to your name, which would be "David" with "D" at address 0x3E8, "a" at address 0x3E9, etc.

Comment: Now, if you store a structure of some sort, that is several values one after another, in memory, you usually get a pointer to (= the address of) the first value and access the following ones using an offset.

Comment: Okay, so a register holds a value, and the values can only be 32 bit, and the farther you go into a register. Like say. . . .%eax being the whole register, %ax being 15-31 in value and %ah being 8 - 15 in value, and %al being 0 - 7 in value, correct? So, if I were to hold something like 0x1008, it would be held in %al, but it would be in the register of %eax?

Comment: No no, you cannot go "farther into a register". The register holds a value which may be intended as memory address. If it is, you need to look up your memory to see the value there, and so on. (You are right there are also al, ah, ax, which are only parts of the register. But that's unrelated to the 0x1000, 0x1004 thing.)

Comment: How do you know what values are in the registers? You do because your code is the one that loads the values into the registers :) The value in a register does not have to be a memory address, it can be any value (except of course if the register is explicitly specified to hold memory address, e.g. CS, DS and such). The offset is 8 because... I think you better read about the [calling convention](http://www.cs.virginia.edu/~evans/cs216/guides/x86.html#calling) in x86 :)

Comment: @m0skit0 yare yare daze. . . @_@ but alright, I'll read about the calling convention.

Comment: What book are you reading?

Comment: Btw as a personal suggestion, x86 is not a recommended architecture to start learning computer architecture and assembly. It is overly complicated (mostly for historical reasons). I would recommend a RISC architecture like Motorola 68K or MIPS to get started. The general concepts are the same and the assembly is much simpler and straightforward.

Comment: @jwdonahue Computer Systems - A programmers perspective, 2nd edition.

Comment: @m0skit0 understood

Comment: If You switch optimizations the code will vanish

Comment: @m0skit0 While I agree with that suggestion from an academic perspective, the truth is it is not as easy to come by architectures other than x86 where you can experiment with what you learned. x86 is abundant in examples and is everywhere, therefore offering the chance to write code you can actually put to use.

Comment: @Havenard There are plenty of emulators for both architectures, and some devices that are MIPS can still be found (e.g. routers). I think for a beginner x86 is overkill to start with (segmentation, virtual 8086/32-bit/64-bit, protected mode, descriptor registers, pagination...). A RISC architecture will teach you the basics and once you feel comfortable enough you can jump to x86. I'm saying this from my own experience.

Answer (score 2):

Because of how the call stack is structured when using [C declaration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#Caller_clean-up).

First the caller will `push` the 4-byte `y`, then the 4-byte `xp` (this order is important so C can support [Variadic Functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function)), then the `call` to your function will implicitly `push` the return address which is also 4-byte (this is a 32-bit program).

The first thing your function does is `push` the state of `ebp` which it will need to recover later so that the caller can continue working properly, and then copy the current state of `esp` (stack pointer) to `ebp`. In sum:

```
push %ebp
movl %esp, %ebp
```

This is also known as [function prologue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_prologue).

When all this is done you are finally ready to actually run the code you wrote, at this stage the stack is something like this:

```
%ebp- ? = address of your local variables (which in this example you don't have)
%ebp+ 0 = address of the saved state of previous ebp
%ebp+ 4 = ret address
%ebp+ 8 = address where is stored the value of xp
%ebp+12 = address where is stored the value of y
%ebp+16 = out of bonds, this memory space belongs to the caller
```

When your function is done it will wrap it up by setting `esp` back to `ebp`, then `pop` the original `ebp` and `ret`.

```
movl %ebp, %esp
pop %ebp
ret
```

`ret` is basically a shortcut to `pop` a pointer from the stack and `jmp` to it.

Edit: Fixed order of parameters for AT&T assembly

Comment: I suggest you draw the stack the other way around because the stack grows down.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie `esp` decreases yes, which means things pushed later are put on top. I think my representation shows that.

Comment: I would say that `ebp+12` is _before_ `ebp+8`, and "top" meaning "down"

Comment: @PaulOgilvie I think that representation just makes things more confusing. The addresses are in order and data is laid in memory exactly like that, the way `esp` behaves is an entirely different matter. If you think your view of the stack is more clarifying, you can put it in your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the normal function entry in assembler:

```
    push ebp
    mov ebp, esp
    sub esp, <size of local variables>
```

So `ebp+4` holds the previous value of `ebp`. Before the old ebp was the return address, at `ebp+8`. Before that are the parameters of the function, in reverse order, so the first parameter is at `ebp+12` and the second at `ebp+8`.

Comment: Note that you are using Intel syntax while the OP was using AT&T syntax. To avoid confusion: One of the most important differences is that most *arguments are reversed*, so `mov ebp, esp` would be `movl %esp, %ebp` and so on.

Comment: I see, but shouldn't ebp+2 hold something as well? Furthermore what about ebp+1 aka 0x1000? (If I'm getting my math right.)

Comment: No, `ebp+2` would not anything real (of course it holds something), because addresses and ints here are 32 bit (= 4 bytes)

Comment: @CherryDT, thanks for the clarification. Unfortunately I don't "speak" the AT&T dialect.

Comment: Alright, so ebp+2 EXISTS, but it doesn't HOLD anything, and because all of the addresses are 32 BIT, they can each only hold information in increments of 2^x % 4 <= 32, correct?

Comment: increments of 32 bits, that is correct. Note that for example chars are converted to ints before being pushed as well.

Comment: @The_Senate well they do hold something, but it's useless. Let's say we have a structure of two DWORDs (DWORD=32-bit value) with values 0x11223344 stored at address 0x1000 and 0xAABBCCDD at address 0x1004. Since such values are stored in a "bottom-up" byte order, in memory you would see this: [...]

Comment: shouldn't the `add esp...' be a `sub esp...' seeing as how the stack grows down?

Comment: @thurizas, yes! Thanks.

Comment: [...] 44 33 22 11 DD CC BB AA. That is, 0x1000 holds 0x44, 0x1001 holds 0x33, etc. - Now if you look at "a DWORD stored at 0x1000", you see 0x11223344, and "a DWORD stored at 0x1004" you see 0xAABBCCDD, as expected. But "a DWORD stored at 0x1002" would be useless, as you'd read 0xCCDD1122.

Comment: @CherryDT Okay, but one thing I'm having a hard time grasping is how 0x1000 and 0x10004 relate to other parts of the register such as : (Let's consider %eax, then we have %ax and %ah and %al. How do these relate to 0x1000 and 0x1004 and 0x1008 and so on?

Comment: The 0x1000 etc that Cherrry mentions refer to adresses. %eax is a 32 bit data register. It can be broken down (often for backward compatibility) into ax (a 16 bit register), consisting of ah and al (2x 8 bit registers).

Comment: @The_Senate: They don't relate directly, only in their concepts. Talking about registers: As Paul mentioned, some registers may be broken down to subregisters, so assigning 0x11223344 to eax will make you read 0x44 for al, 0x33 for ah and 0x3344 for ax, for example. When I was talking about 0x1000 and 0x1004 I was talking about addresses in memory. (At some point, you probably have an address in the register, let's say you have 0x1000 in eax. Then you would "dereference" eax to read from the memory it points to, i.e. 0x1000. But at this point we are not talking about ah/al, etc.)

Comment: The concepts are similar though: If you are storing eax (a 32-bit value) into 0x1000 (meaning: into the 4 bytes in memory from 0x1000 to 0x1003), you would be able to read 1 byte from 0x1001 and get what was previously ah, for example. (But reading *4 bytes* from 0x1001 would get you garbage as I explained above.)

Comment: To explain it differently: Memory is just a pool of data, sequentially ordered, each byte having an address. Registers are like a tiny piece of memory but built into the processor and with name. For both, their _meaning_ is not defined, it's something you need to define (by looking at things the right way). If I put 12 34 56 78 9A into memory at address 0 (so 9A would be at address 4), I can look at "an 8-bit value at address 2" and get 56 (=0x56), "a 16-bit value at address 1" and get 34 56 (=0x5634), "a 32-bit value at address 1" and get 34 56 78 9A (=0x9A785634) or anything else etc. [...]

Comment: [...] similarly, I can store 12 34 56 78 into eax and then I see eax as 0x78563412, ax as 0x3412, ah as 0x34 and al as 0x12. (The registers and subregisters have names and not addresses.) Similar concepts, but not the same thing here.

Comment: Now, memory access often involves registers as well - with a fixed address, you would have a register as source/destination when writing/reading memory (in this case, the amount of bytes you read/write is defined by the size of the (sub)register you use!), and with a variable/calculated address, you would also have the memory address in a register (and it's possible to calculate an address using an offset, so having the value 0x1000 in eax and accessing 4(%eax) would access address eax+4 = 0x1004). I hope this cleared things up a bit. :)